# Is it possible to revoke a valid SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

Our client is asking us to migrate a list of internal facing Java projects to use SSL for making potentially sensitive REST calls. They are planning to generate and sign the certificates internally.

I am concerned that in case a certificate is ever compromised, an application might wish to revoke their certificate.

Is it possible to revoke certificates programmatically without changing the master? It seems once the hash signature is established, there would be no way to revoke it, but then how do agencies like Verisign do it?

Comment: Are all these certificates self-signed certificates or are you creating internal CAs and using them to sign the end-entity certs? Also, are you familiar with CRLs? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list

Comment: @Rahul We are creating an internal CA and master that will be used to generate and sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificates include as part of their information how to check revocation, normally a CRL (Certificate Revocation List)  or online service OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol)

A certification service provider revoke a certificate by including it in the CRL and its OCSP service. When the customer wants to check revocation of a certificate download the CRL to check or performs an OCSP request

To that could be done you would need:
1) Have a OCSP service and / or CRL
2) Include in the self-generated certificate the URL to OCSP/CRL.
3) Revoke certificates including them in the list of your revocation service

For example, for secure HTTPS websites the browser is responsible for performing revocation checking. However [Google decided in 2012 to default Chrome not to check for certificate revocation on non-EV certificates](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/02/05/crlsets.html)

Therefore, be aware that control of revocation is client responsibility and could not do

Answer (score 1):

Revoking a certificate without deleting the certificate authority that signed that certificate is one of the basics of working with certificates.

As explained above, there are two ways to check if a certificate is revoked: by checking with a dedicated server (OCSP) or by checking a static file that you download every so often (CRL).

You can setup a test OCSP server easily using openssl.
And you can also generate a CRL file using openssl. A CRL file looks a bit like a certificate or a csr (usually kept in base 64). You can use an online CRL decoder here:
http://developerutils.com/CRLDecoder.php